# Resizing the minibuffer to fit an image displayed there

Tags: emacs, elisp

One can display an image in the current buffer by executing:

```
(insert-image (create-image "image.png"))
```

I would like to know how to display an image, not in the current buffer, but in the **minibuffer** at the bottom of the screen.

Using `(select-window (active-minibuffer-window))` to select the minibuffer does not seem to work--for some reason `(active-minibuffer-window)` returns `nil`.

Any ideas?  Many thanks!

**Update:**

Now I know how to display an image in the minibuffer:

```
(with-current-buffer (window-buffer (minibuffer-window))
  (insert-image (create-image "image.png")))
```

What I don't know is how to resize the minibuffer so that the image fits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK.  So after some trial and error, here's the function I wanted:

```
(defun my-show-image-in-minibuffer (filename)
  (let* ((img (create-image filename))
         (y   (floor (cdr (image-size img)))))
    (with-current-buffer (window-buffer (minibuffer-window))
      (setq resize-mini-windows 'grow-only)
      (setq resize-mini-windows nil)
      (delete-minibuffer-contents)
      (window-resize (minibuffer-window) y)
      (insert-image img))
    (clear-this-command-keys t)
    (read-event)
    (with-current-buffer (window-buffer (minibuffer-window))
      (delete-minibuffer-contents)
      (window-resize (minibuffer-window) (- 0 y))
      (setq resize-mini-windows 'grow-only))
    (image-flush img)
    (setq unread-command-events (list last-input-event))))
```

Additionally, after any key is pressed, it deletes the image and returns the minibuffer to its normal size.